# Angular get special characters from URL

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using angular 10 and I have url which included a token. Something like :
register-confirmation?token=ONPhEh1ANYTtd%252F42PPLLNaUovdIvy5a4NPZ5JmueDnyusF5TUn%252F0CQhIXdwv2vE

I have to capture the token so make an api cal from the app but if I used activated route, all instances of %25 from the token are replaced by %. I have tried using encodeURI and encodeURIComponent. I believe there is a decodeURI and decodeURIComponent as well. Which one will cover all scenarios of special characters that are part of the token in my url.
Need help to fix this.

Comment: `decodeURIComponent` made to decode the component of an URI however both works pretty similar. One note I would add here is, chrome does encode URI automatically so you need to check how many times URI actually encoded.

Comment: Please provide some code so we can tell what kind of api call you are trying to make. `%25` is the encoded version of the `%` symbol, so if you get the token using `ActivatedRoute` it is expected you get the unencoded version. You should be using the `HttpClient` to make http requests, and setting the unencoded token as a query parameter. `HttpClient` should handle the encoding automatically.